# List works using XML but not HTML, why?

Tags: html, css, xml, xhtml

My drop down menu works perfect in XML and not in HTML. Please view this fiddle for a visual presentation: http://jsfiddle.net/H8FVE/9/
If you hover your mouse over the ***MORE*** button, you will see that the drop down aligns fine. The code I use for the drop down bit is:

```
<moretopbar>
<ul>
    <li class="mgames"><a href="" style="border-bottom:9px solid #e34328">Games</a></li>
    <li class="mliterature"><a href="" style="border-bottom:9px solid #2c8f83">Literature</a></li>
    <li class="marts"><a href="" style="border-bottom:9px solid #cc226a">Arts</a></li>
    <li class="mcontact" style="background:none;"><a href="" style="border-bottom:9px solid #9395aa">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</moretopbar>
```

And some CSS:

```
#mega div moretopbar {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin-left:1px;
    margin-right:1px;
    width: 495px;
    height: 74px;
    background-image: url(images/morebgwide.png);
    background-size:495px 74px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

I tried to change the `<moretopbar>` to `<div id="moretopbar">` but it messed up the drop down completely.

Why is that? And how should I fix it so that I use HTML only? Feel free to update the fiddle if you choose to answer: http://jsfiddle.net/H8FVE/9/

Before you choose to answer I should note two things. Firstly, I am not familiar with XML, the above is a coding mistake that randomly worked for me (and someone pointed out it was XML), and secondly, is there a reason of why I shouldn't use it this way? For instance compatibility issues...

Comment: You should not use it this way because if a machine expects HTML, you should give it (valid) HTML, or you might introduce some bugs that are hard to identify. Simply write valid HTML and you should be fine. HTML defines a limited set of tags, and `<moretopbar>` is not one of them.

Comment: Thank you for the respond, but how do I make my code a valid HTML then? How do I change the **<moretopbar>** to **<div id="moretopbar">** without breaking the design?

Comment: Normally it should not break your design. Let me check that fiddle. Edit: next time, please create a narrowed-down demo. Don't expect people to crawl through this thousand-lines mess you put in that jsFiddle.

Comment: @bažmegakapa According to an answer here, it forgot to declare moretopbar as an id. However, I changed **#mega div moretopbar** to **#mega div #moretopbar {** in my stylesheet but it did not work. Am I declaring it incorrectly?

Comment: Aaaghh... I looked at the code on jsFiddle... By the way, jsFiddle already declares a doctype and `head`, so all you need to do is insert the code inside `body` into the `HTML` section. You can change settings by clicking `Info` on the panel on the left. Also, jsFiddle already applies reset styles (resets heading tags too, really annoying), so you don't need to put your reset CSS in the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your HTML is totally invalid. **You are opening a lot of divs and not closing them all.** That is why your design breaks when you introduce one more div.

Please fix your HTML. You can use [W3c's Online Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check) to see problems with your markup. Make writing valid HTML your habit, otherwise expect to get "strange" errors like this.

In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H8FVE/10/), I made the following changes:

- Moved the ID to your `<ul>` and got rid of `<moretopbar>`:

  ```
  <ul id="moretopbar">
  ```
- Changed the selector to: `#mega div #moretopbar`.

It "works" because the ID is now on an `ul`, not a `div` - as I already mentioned, the browser cannot really identify which div is which because of the lack of closing tags. Unless you fix this problem you are very very likely to see other strange bugs with your current divs.

---

**Edit:** Also the following CSS rules need to be more specific than simply saying `div`:

```
#mega div {...}
#mega li.dif:hover div {...}
```

For example you can use a `specialdiv` class on the div you mean these rules for, and use `.specialdiv` instead of `div` in the rules.

[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/H8FVE/13/)

Comment: "Make writing valid HTML your habit, otherwise expect to get strange errors like this." == +42

Comment: Oh note that the Fiddle I presented was only part of my code. I tried to rip off the part that was relevant with this question, therefore, there are a great few divs there without being closed. I did not think that it would affect it this much in this case.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson Imagine being the browser. You have 34 opening divs and 28 closing divs. Which one closes which?

Comment: I came to a similar conclusion. Nice answer. CSS does not follow the hierachy of DOM elements (HTML tags) but of selectors and specificity.  The div is part of the selector, so you need to take care. If even the HTML is broken, good luck.

Comment: Okay, in an attempt to ensure that your answer is correct, I made sure to close all the Divs as suggested, and changed selector to **#mega div #moretopbar** and used **<div id="moretopbar">** but it still appeared broken, it was aligned incorrectly. Are you sure that the issue at hand is the closing of Divs? Cheers for your input regardless.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson Validate your page on the link I have given. Fix errors until it says your page is valid. At that point we can restart investigation, but I'm quite sure it will solve the problem - or at least not create new ones. If the problem still exists, be sure to post a new (valid) fiddle, so I can help you further.

Comment: @bažmegakapa Alright I have cleared the body part and ensured that all Divs are closed properly, I have added comments too. The issue still remains, please have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/H8FVE/12/

Comment: @HenrikPetterson Next problem is this line: `#mega div {`. These rules apply to ALL divs inside `#mega`, so even to your `#moretopbar` div. Try to use classes (`class="specialdiv"` -> `.specialdiv`) for those divs that you need these rules for - or just make this rule more specific any other way.

Comment: Applies to `#mega li.dif:hover div` as well - div is not specific enough here. I produced [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H8FVE/13/) which seems to finally work (a bit narrowed down).

Comment: Can you please provide me an example of this through fiddle? I am trying to understand how specific I should make it and how to use the class as you proposed.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson Updated my answer with instructions and a new fiddle - `class="specialdiv"` is added and the two offending CSS rules changed.

Comment: Oh I see what you did there. Thank you for hanging in there and explaining this to me. I have a problem understanding code until I see a working example, especially when I have been trying to wrap my brain around it for 15 hours. Nonetheless, answer upvoted and accepted.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson Happy to help. And if this leads to one more people writing valid HTML code, it was already worth it :).

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to declare moretopbar as an id aka #moretopbar

Comment: Sorry can you please elaborate on that? Where did I forget that?

Comment: If you change it to <div id="moretopbar"> you need to declare that in the css since "moretopbar" is no longer a tag.

Comment: I tried changing this **#mega div moretopbar {** to this **#mega div #moretopbar {** but it did not work. More info would be helpful

Comment: Nice guess but without trying. The answer is not that trivial.

Comment: Still part of the answer and a correct statment ;) I was lazy and didn't dig through all of his jsfiddle code